# Echo total in array codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

How to echo total out of array created from
Model

```
Function count {
     $this->db->select('user_id, COUNT(user_id) as total);
     $this->db->group_by('user_id'); 
     $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
     $query = $this->db->get('tablename', 10);
    Return $query->result_array();}
```

Controller data [total] = $this->mymodel->count();

Vardump get the count function current as arrays with

```
Array = user_id => 1
              Total. => 2 for examle
```

I.need to echo total in view

Comment: `print_r()` and post the data

Comment: Can I use total as var

Comment: yes you can. To provide answer add `print_r` output

Comment: It's the same as var_dump I just need to echo the total in array

Comment: `echo $user_id['Total']` try this

Comment: Total isn't an index to be echoed this way

Comment: You have to create two different function to get total number of users and 10 record of users.

Comment: Thanks parth for replying I managed to echo the on the fly objects through foreach however if u have another way I would be glad to know